# Trouble checking radio inputs of the same class?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm at the point in this quiz where I want to start checking for the answer given and update the score accordingly. However, when I tried to .check the inputs for each question my quiz stopped working all together. I have made the correct answer between all the questions have the same class so when that class is chosen they get +1 point.

My question is, is having the same class between the different correct answers what's causing this or something else? Heres the code that I'm trying to get to check every input for the correct answer:

```
var checked= $('.CA').checked;

         if(checked){
            total++;
            alert('Your score is '+total);
        };
        else{
            alert('Your score is still '+ total)
        };
```

Here's an example question it would apply to:

```
<div id="question1" class="div" name="Q1[0,0]">
    <p>What is the capital of Washington?</p>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="answer1a" name="Q">Salem
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="answer1b" name="Q">Seattle
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" class="CA" name="Q">Olympia
    <br>
    <input type="radio" class="input" id="answer1d" name="Q">Helena
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/mmac71se/) as well. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop to go iterate all the class CA

try doing like this

```
$('.CA').each(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        total++;
        alert('Your score is '+total);
    };
    else{
        alert('Your score is still '+ total);
    }
});
```

Comment: I like the idea, but I still can't get it to work. Like as soon as I add that bit of code, my quiz just quits functioning.

Comment: you mean the whole script not working or something else ?

Comment: The submit and restart buttons are the only thing shown. The display of my actual quiz questions disappears.  Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zach94/xb7ufjep/) if you don't know what I mean.

Comment: in your CSS, you set .div {display:none;}. How do you expect them to show?

Comment: When the .activequestion class is added, it changes the display to block. If you remove the portion of code attempting to check the input boxes you'll see that it works, but for some reason with that added it disrupts something.

Comment: mate, you have a semicolon outside if and else block. And a lot of missing semicolon in your code. If you hit the JSHint button on jsfiddle, you will see where your errors are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85055/discussion-between-jack-le-and-zach94).